# Beer Lambert law when complex is tetragonal (Jahn-Teller elongated)

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, physical-chemistry, coordination-compounds, transition-metals, uv-vis-spectroscopy

I wondered what modifications there would be to the Beer Lambert law to find the molar extinction coefficients for the solution if the solvent contained the ligands which bind to the metal centre of a metal compound (ie 2 ligands add along the z axis only) and the complex was tetragonal?

Comment: As far you can define a concentration, that is as far you can identify a molecular or heavily bond entity nothing change. Stoichiometry  always count of course, if you are following a process.

Comment: You must find a wavelength that only the complex absorbs, then its the same as normal